# Is it permissible to omit "of them" in the following case?

Tags: grammar, sentence

> I spotted a rottweiler while walking on the trail. What was one (of them) doing in a forest like this?

Is the *of them* necessary? Can it be omitted?

Comment: It would make a little more sense to say *What was it doing*... You can drop the *of them* when there are multiples: *I saw two boys; one was carrying a box of rocks.* But, yes, you can write your sentence that way. *One* is understood to mean *a rottweiler*.

Comment: If you wanted to avoid referring to the dog as 'it' (which would actually be a perfectly suitable way to refer to it), you could say something like "What was such a {dog / creature} doing in a forest like this?"

Answer (score 2):

I would say that it's highly preferable to say "What was it doing…" as "What was one doing…" could easily be mistaken for the impersonal pronoun "one."

Answer (score 1):

The pronoun "*one*" can carry a different connotation in contrast to "*it*".

```
 However, for an average reader, both "one and it" will make sense while you drop 
 the "of them".
```

I spotted a rottweiler while walking on the trail. What was **one**/*it* doing in a forest like this?

**One:**

> used as a pronoun for an unspecified single person, 
>   whereas

**it :**

> indicates a specific object or collection.

Comment: The issue with _one_ is that it refers usually to a person. So the sentence can be read as if the speaker is wondering what a person is doing there - presumably that person is walking that dog.